# CTRL-C does not work in remote session

Tags: linux, shell

I wrote a remote shell tool which works like a "relayed ssh".  It can be configured to run `/bin/bash` or `/bin/login` when user connect to the remote server.

I found a strange problem: if it runs `/bin/bash`, `CTRL-C` will not work, e.g. if I run `tail -f /var/log/syslog`, and then hit `CTRL-C`, it will not terminate `tail`, but just echo `^C` on screen.

However, if it runs `/bin/login`, `CTRL-C` works as it should.  How can I make it work even when running BASH directly?

**EDIT**

I started bash with `-i`, then it works. If I provide `-l`, it still does not work. From the man page of BASH, I only see how to start bash in **interactive** mode, and what file does it load in that mode. But didn't explain **what is** interactive mode, and how bash functions differently in interactive/non-interactive mode, or, more fundamantally, **why there are two modes in bash, for what purpose**??

Comment: [mcve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367019/10765659) please, if possible.

Comment: the problem is the remote process is not getting SIGINT, the reason is unclear - need much more information

Comment: I started bash with `-i`, then it works.  If I provide `-l`, it still does not work.  From the man page of BASH, I only see how to start bash in "interactive" mode, and what file does it load in that mode. But didn't explain **what is** interactive mode, and how bash functions differently in interactive/non-interactive mode, or, more fundamantally, why there are two modes in bash, for what purpose??

Comment: (1) I find this question quite interesting. Reading an answer may be fun. Investigating and writing an answer may be more fun; but without mcve it may not. (2) Does your edit mean that originally you run `/bin/bash` non-interactively (the output from `echo "$-"` does not contain `i`)? (3) Does "if I provide `-l`" mean "if I provide `-l` along `-i`"? or "if I provide `-l` instead of `-i`"?

Comment: It's unclear if OP's special environment provides a TTY or not. CTRL-C is handled through a TTY.

Comment: A few links from other stacks: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/629796/how-exactly-a-ctrlc-passes-a-signal-to-process , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45993444/in-detail-what-happens-when-you-press-ctrl-c-in-a-terminal

Comment: @A.B I use https://github.com/creack/pty to provide a PTY